# Tape Drive - reading and understanding unknown tape data - is there an index stored somewhere?

Tags: java, linux

We have tons of MLR/SLR tapes with audio recording that we'd like to extract. We do not have the software that wrote these tapes, neither does the original developer have the source code for this application (it's way too old). However we do have a "read only" version of this application, but it requires enourmous amount of manual clicking, selecting small audio chunks, extract, etc etc repeat it repeat it, and this is not an option when we have ~2000 tapes.

We've done a 'dd' in linux on the tapes in order to dump them to a harddrive and I've spent tons of hours figuring out how it's stored on tape, and I am now able to extract MPEG audio, and HTML-files / word document files stored on the tape, so I'm nearly done with this, and I'm kinda satisified, kinda.

The thing that bugs me is that the "read only"-software that reads the tape has no problem figuring out EVERYTHING regarding the tape, and I'm not able to find any kind of index in the enourmous file that we've dumped to disk. I've analyzed several. The "read only" software spends 5-10 seconds and then lists all the files contained within the tape.

Is there some way that the tape might contain a separate track that contains the index and we've somehow missed it? I would assume this would be in the first couple of 100 bytes of the tape, but that's not the case. The audio data starts after 1024 bytes of almost only 0-bytes. The data that is not 0-bytes of the first 1024 is a short string indicating the name of the file that follows + the chunk size of the data. Then a new 'header'-chunk comes along describing the next data chunk, and so it goes on and on and on, but aboslutely no index.

What other way could this index be stored as it appears that the "read only" app spends < 10 seconds before the tape content is available for extraction, and I'm quite convinced it doesn't read the entire tape in < 10 seconds.

Comment: Is this not a standard `tar` archive? They do not have indices, but format seems very similar.

Comment: What does `file your_dump.bin` tells about the format?

Comment: No, it's not a standard tar archive. The stuff was written to the tape using a windows application, back in the previous millennia. It's a totally obscure and proprietary format, which the developer is now retired and could not find the source code. It's an app written in Delphi.

Comment: SubOptimal: I'll check tomorrow when I'm back at work. (in 16 hours, that is)

Comment: SubOptimal: when I run the 'file' command, it just says 'data'.